# Visual Studio 2019 - Git Source Control: Como habilitar el marcador visual de comparación de commits en la ventana de Administracion de Ramas?

Tags: visual-studio, git, visual-studio-2019

Tengo Visual Studio 2019. En la ventana del Administrador de Ramas (Manage Branches) tenía activada una característica, que a mi me parece muy útil, con la cual la interfaz de usuario del Administrador de Ramas señalaba con un marcador en color rojo los commits de la rama que se estaba explorando que coincidían con alguno de los HEAD de las ramas locales. Para darme a entender, adjunto una imagen. A los marcadores que me refiero son los que encerré en el rectángulo de esquinas redondeadas de color verde.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas marcas me eran útiles para darme cuenta que ramas locales ya había subido a las ramas remotas, lo cual lograba explorando la rama remota. De este modo podía darme cuenta que ramas locales ya no necesitaba en mi área de trabajo.

Hace un tiempo noté que esa marcación desapareció, y la verdad me ahorraba tiempo a la hora de limpiar el área de trabajo porque ahora debo tomar nota de los HEAD de las ramas locales y compararlos con los de la rama que estoy explorando.

La pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo volver a activar esta característica en Visual Studio? ¿O fue algo que se me deshabilitó en el Git?

La imagen la tome de la [Documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-browse-repository?view=vs-2022). No puedo tomar una de mi interfaz de usuario, porque no podría ilustrar cuales son las marcas a las que me refiero porque ya no me salen.

Un saludo y Gracias a quien me pueda colaborar con su valiosa respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando intente publicar mi pregunta en la plataforma [Microsoft Q&A](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/vs-general.html), la misma me sugirió revisar esta pregunta: [What does master tag mean in history for Git in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444906/what-does-master-tag-mean-in-history-for-git-in-visual-studio-2019). Leyendo la respuesta publicada por Chad B encontré la respuesta a mi pregunta también.

La Vista de Grafo, que es la misma vista que la interfaz de usuario muestra para "Historial de Rama" en el panel derecho de "Repositorio Git" (la que se muestra cuando haces click en la opcion "Administrar Ramas") tiene dos botones arriba para administrar cual conjunto de ramas se muestran marcadas con la etiqueta roja por la que preguntaba. Los botones son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Traduciendo lo que Chad B explica:

La barra en la ventana de historial tiene tres botones donde puedes conmutar para ver las ramas locales, las ramas remotas y las etiquetas sobre los commits correspondientes. Por defecto, las ramas se renderizan en rojo y las etiquetas en verde. Pasando el puntero del ratón sobre la etiqueta también dice si es una rama o una etiqueta

La cita original:

> "The toolbar in the History window has three buttons on it where you
> can toggle seeing local branches, remote tracking branches, and tags
> labeled onto the corresponding commits. By default, branches are
> rendered red and tags are green. Hovering the mouse over the label
> should also tell you if it's a branch or tag."

Para esta pregunta debería usar el botón "Show Local Branches"